# Static cells in UITableViewController opening different URL on the same nib

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

I am quite new to UITableViewController, I would like to make a static cells UITableViewController and each static cells open up the same nib file but the URL of the UIWebView will be different. e.g. row 1 will open google.com and row 2 in yahoo.com.  May I know how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to implement the tableview delegate method, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, this will allow you to ask the tableview which cell was selected and then take the appropriate action.  An example would be:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"google"]) {
        // open google
    } else if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"yahoo"]) {
        // open yahoo
    }
}
```

**EDIT TO ANSWER THE QUESTION ASKED IN COMMENTS**

You didn't state this, but from reading your question, I'm guessing you are using separate nib files and want to push another view controller on screen that controls a web view when the user selects one of the static cells.  The steps to do this are to:

1. Create the new VC
2. Give the public property the URL you want to load
3. Push the VC on screen

in code that will look something like:

```
 WebViewController webVC = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"your nib name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 webVC.url = // some NSURL object, or maybe just a string that has the URL - that's up to you
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:webVC animated:YES]
```

Comment: But how can i connect it to the next nib UIwebView? What code i need to add in the next nib? Thanks